# java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type java.util.ArrayList<kotlin.String?>{ kotlin.collections.Typst<kotlin.String?> }

Tags: android, kotlin

here is my code

```
private fun getProductDetails(proId: String?) {

    Firebase.firestore.collection("products")
        .document(proId!!).get().addOnSuccessListener {
            val list = it.get("productImages") as ArrayList<String>
            binding.textView7.text = it.getString("productName")
            binding.textView8.text = it.getString("productSp")
            binding.textView9.text = it.getString("productDescription")

            val slideList = ArrayList<SlideModel>()
            for (data in list){
                slideList.add(SlideModel(data, ScaleTypes.CENTER_CROP))
            }
            binding.imageSlider.setImageList(slideList)

        }.addOnFailureListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }
```

My app is crashing.

Comment: Probably it means that `it.get("productImages")` is returning null. Have you tried debugging it to see what values are being returned? Add some print or log statements? You should probably read up on kotlin and null types. Unrelated to this crash I think, but why do you pass in a nullable `proId` and then call `proId!!`? That will fail if you ever pass in a null value, so you should just change the argument to `String` instead of `String?`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by tyler, you are trying to assign nullable collection to non-nullable collection which is causing the crash

```
Firebase.firestore.collection("products")
  .document(proId!!).get()
  .addOnSuccessListener {
     val list = it.get("productImages") as ArrayList<String?>
     binding.textView7.text = it.getString("productName")
     binding.textView8.text = it.getString("productSp")
     binding.textView9.text = it.getString("productDescription")
     binding.imageSlider.setImageList(list.mapNotNull{ SlideModel(it, ScaleTypes.CENTER_CROP) })
  }.addOnFailureListener {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
  }
```

Comment: It's actually the list object itself that's null, that's why the cast is failing (which is what Tyler's getting at)

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying you're trying to cast an object to `ArrayList<String>`, but that object is actually *null*, so you get a `NullPointerException` (i.e. *"this thing you thought was an object is actually null, there's nothing there"*).

You're doing that here:

```
val list = it.get("productImages") as ArrayList<String>
```

which means your `get` call is failing and returning `null`, because there's no value for the `"productImages"` key.

---

The safe way to handle this would be using the null-safe `as?` operator:

```
val list = it.get("productImages") as? ArrayList<String>
```

which returns *null* if the cast failed. That means `list` is nullable, requiring null-checking if you're going to use it. One way you could do that:

```
val slideList = list?.map { data ->
    SlideModel(data, ScaleTypes.CENTER_CROP)
} ?: emptyList()
```

i.e. if `list` is non-null, transform all the items to create a new list, otherwise default to an empty list